# Simple query conversion from sql to mdx

Tags: sql, ssas, mdx, cube, olap-cube

```
    select MAX(InsertionDT),TaskStatus,tasksubstatus 
    from TransTasksFFMS_GVT 
    where TaskCode = 323155 group by TaskStatus,tasksubstatus
```

To use this query in the cube browser I have created a name query and used it as a dimension and it works, however I'm asked to do the calculation as a measure. Is it possible to translate this query to mdx to use it as the expression in a calculation?

What the query does: Returns the max insertion date for a each pair of status and sub status.

I'm new to MDX and to the whole cube idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, first make the whole thing a star schema with a fact table/view and a dimension table for the tasks containing Task code, status, and substatus. Then define a measure for the InsertionDt using `Max` as the aggregation function.

Comment: I have created the star schema and tested the output using the fn as a named query however as mentioned I'd like to use a measure instead. Can you please elaborate on your last point about the aggregation function?

Comment: For others to benefit: I created a measure and used the max fn as follows: Max([DimTableName][InsertionDT]), displayed the results and then used the measure to calculate the maximum! Much easier than a named query and much more efficient as expected!